# Why add-in concatenates strings rather than appending in Outlook Calendar Location field?

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-calendar

**Platform:** Calendar in Outlook Web Access (only, not in other clients) in Office 365

**Scenario:** We have an add-in that adds an URL to the location field of invitation in calendar. If there is a text before the click of add-in, on add-in click the populated URL gets concatenated to the existing text by a semi-colon.

**Problem:** This behaviour not only makes the URL un-clickable but also starts showing the newly concatenated text as room or location info for that user in further invites. The same text then traverses to the Outlook Calendar client as well.

**What we have done in code:** We set location using setAsync() call on Office.context.mailbox.item.location

How to fix this problem? We do not want the strings to be concatenated?

Comment: Hi Shubh, do you have a video you could share with us that demonstrates the problem? We can't reproduce it on our side (perhaps we are misunderstanding something in your report though). Also could you share the exact code you're calling?

Comment: Hi @outlook-add-ins-team-msft, Thank you for looking into it. You can have a look at this video link [ https://youtu.be/GCQoPNdV9uU ]. First we add a room, then click add-in to add URL, then we add another room. Post the invitation is sent, we come back to the invite and see first room and URL has been concatenated as one unit and second room stays as another unit. Below is the code: `var locationWithInvitation = “https://www.sample.com”;
return Q.oinvoke(Office.context.mailbox.item.location, "setAsync", locationWithInvitation);`